# Internal memory management after Android Market update

Tags: android

I put my app on the Android Market. Now I want update it, but before I would like to understand better how Android will manage the memory of my app.
In particular I used Internal Memory for example in this way:

```
File f = context.getFileStreamPath(NAME_FILE);
if (f.exists()){
    FileInputStream stream = context.openFileInput(NAME_FILE);
    ObjectInputStream din = new ObjectInputStream(stream);
    myobject = (MyObject) din.readObject();
}else{
    FileOutputStream stream = ctx.openFileOutput(NAME_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream dout = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);
        dout.writeObject(myobject);
        dout.flush();
        stream.getFD().sync();
}
```

And I used this file to store some serializable objects. In the new version I changed the structure of these objects and so my question is:

in the new update, will Android delete this file and when my app will try to store objects (else clause) into the file it will create a new empty file?
Or will Android keep this file and when my app will try to fit objects from file (if clause) it will crash?

Tnx in advance.
Framentos

Comment: android puts all files you write to the filesystem in /data/namespace.of.app/ so, if you don't change the package name or file name it's going to come back true for f.exists() as all that asks "Is does this file exist?". Then it'll try to read the objects and unserialize them back as type MyObject.

Comment: [Search this page for the section about "Version Control"](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). It depends on two factors: the old serialized class and the new one must have a matching serialVersionUID and the changes must be "compatible", meaning you can remove / add fields without a problem. But you probably cannot change their types.

Comment: @ewanm89 : *"android puts all files you write to the filesystem in /data/namespace.of.app/"* - Not necessarily. Never assume absolute paths for any particular version of Android, from any particular manufacturer, for any particular device.

Comment: @Squonk point is it won't change just updating by the application.

Comment: yeah, /data/ is where it'll be on stock aosp roms, but unless you are asking for full filesystem access you aren't going to care anyway. It'll still be under a directory tree derived from the package name.

Answer (score 0):

> in the new update, will Android delete this file...?

No, an update to a previously installed app does not delete previous saved data.

If your data structures have changed then your new version needs to detect the existence of previous stored data and delete/recreate it the first time the new (upgraded) version is run.